# Step by step implementation of Swagger for Spring MVC Rest project?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, swagger

Can anyone please help me with step by step implementation of Swagger for a Spring MVC Rest project which does not use Spring Boot? I have googled lot of sites but was not able to implement successfully. Thank you

Comment: What is your problem specifically? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Check this github project swagger-spring-mvc: https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc-example

Comment: See http://Springfox.io